# How to load a language file in a module call by a component in joomla 2.5?

Tags: module, joomla2.5, custom-component

I use a google analytics module "mod_ga_dash" call by a view of my own component.

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('ganalytics');

foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

My module works great but I'ld like to load my fr-FR.mod_ga_dash.ini in default.php.

```
|myJoomla
_|administrator
__|components
___|myComponent
____|views
_____|ganalytics
______|tmpl
_______|default.php //call module
__|modules
___|mod_ga_dash
____|languages
_____|fr-FR
______|fr-FR.mod_ga_dash.ini //want load this file
```

I try this !

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('ganalytics');

//load FR file language
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
$extension = 'mod_ga_dash';
$base_dir = JURI::base().'modules'.DS.$extension.DS;
echo $base_dir.'<br>';
$language_tag = 'fr-FR';
print_r($language->load($extension, $base_dir, $language_tag, true));

foreach($modules as $module)
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

Someone can help me, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base directory is wrong, the base should identify where the language file you want to load is located in the front or back end.  I'm pretty sure the GA Dashboard is a back end module so the language load call should look like this.

```
$language->load($extension, JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, $language_tag, true)
```

That should load the language file you want.

Comment: A long time ago in a galaxy far far away ... Thanks for answer ^^